# .htaccess - redirect dynamic url's from multiple domains to single dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic

I have an odd situation, where the client had been using multiple domains for the same site, but wasn't using 301 redirects on them. So the search engines have indexed:

```
www.site1.com/pageid=2
www.site2.com/pageid=2
www.site3.com/pageid=2
www.site4.com/pageid=2
```

all for the same page. I now need to redirect (all of them) to
    www.site1.com/about

In the past I've successfully used this format:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=2$
RewriteRule ^/?site/$ http://www.site.com/about/ [L,R=301]
```

but that was just from a single domain. Is there a way to tell it to redirect that same page on site2, site3, and site4 also for the list of pages?

I'd like to keep this all within the same .htaccess file if at all possible.

Comment: If all domains are pointing to the same site, the About of `domain1` is the same About of `domain4`. The domains are sharing the content. There is no About of `domainx`, there is only one About or page or whatever. Redirection most probably will end up in loops, I guess.

Comment: can you explain what this means? this is a wordpress site with permalinks on. i am redirecting from a dynamic .asp site, to a wordpress site with permalinks (ie it's already using mod_rewrite)

Comment: My point is all sites are sharing the same content, so page1, for example, is physically the same page for all sites and that's because the content is physically the same for all sites, according to your question `...using multiple domains for the same site`. Therefore, the URLs or whatever is used to point to that content are irrelevant, because all go to the same physical content.

Comment: thank you -- you were right. the issue was that our network admins had not pointed site2, site3, site4 to site1 on their end, and my htaccess wasn't working any way.